# Allocated memory error in recursive function

Tags: php, memory, recursion, out-of-memory

I'm trying to create an encrypter on my website using PHP. I've created the same thing before using Lua so I'm currently trying to port it over, however it's erroring claiming I've exhausted too much memory, yet I'm not sure what could be causing this:

```
function offsetASCII($OrigByte, $Offset) {
    $OrigByte = $OrigByte + $Offset;
    if ($OrigByte > $MaxASCII) {
        return offsetASCII($MinASCII, $OrigByte-$MaxASCII);
    } else {
        return $OrigByte;
    }
}
```

The idea is that it keeps offsetting the number OrigByte by the number Offset. If the new value for OrigByte is greater than the maximum allowed value, then it repeats the function making OrigByte the minimum allowed value, and it makes Offset the "leftover" amount that it went over the maximum value by. This repeats until it's within the maximum value, and then it returns it.

The error is:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in [PageDirectoryHere] on line 49

Line 49 is:

```
return offsetASCII($MinASCII, $OrigByte-$MaxASCII);
```

OrigByte could be any letter converted into its ASCII value. MinASCII and MaxASCII are the minimum and maximum values for capital letters in ASCII (65 and 90). Offset originally is rand($MinASCII, $MinASCII+25).

I'm clueless to why this is happening, so thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Increase memory limit in php.ini

Comment: Why are you trying to create an encrypter? What is it for? Because you should never roll your own crypto.

Comment: Since we don't know any information about the actual data that you're using the best answer we can give you is "because PHP has exhausted all of its available memory".

Comment: OrigByte could be any letter converted into its ASCII value. MinASCII and MaxASCII are the minimum and maximum values for capital letters in ASCII (65 and 90). Offset originally is rand($MinASCII, $MinASCII+25).

Comment: What's `$MinASCII`? You don't seem to be declaring it which may mean that its going to be 0 every time you recurse .

Comment: They are the minimum and maximum values for capital letters in ASCII (65 and 90).

Comment: `$MinASCII` and `$MaxASCII` are not within your function scope.

Comment: Do they need to be within the scope? I'm new to PHP but I assumed setting them before the function would be acceptable: http://prntscr.com/apaibj

Comment: @Vaeb [They do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If you use anonymous functions you can use [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-197) otherwise you'd have to use [globals](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php). I'd recommend making a class, though.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I tried adding them in as parameters but it's still displaying the same error.

Comment: Revise your code logic and let us know why you think it should work the way it's written.

Comment: Aha you were right @h2ooooooo and apokryfos, however there was also an issue with where I was calling the function. It's resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: @Vaeb Make sure you answer your own question with the solution so others can figure it out in case they have the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
function offsetASCII($OrigByte, $Offset, $MinASCII, $MaxASCII) {
    $OrigByte = $OrigByte + $Offset;
    if ($OrigByte > $MaxASCII) {
        return offsetASCII($MinASCII, $OrigByte-$MaxASCII, $MinASCII, $MaxASCII);
    } else {
        return $OrigByte;
    }
}

$EncryptedChar = chr(offsetASCII($NowByte, $NewKeyNums[$Iter], 65, 90));
```

The first thing I was doing wrong was trying to use $MinASCII and $MaxASCII outside of the scope of the function (I solved by adding them as parameters).

The second thing I was doing wrong was defining $MinASCII and $MaxASCII outside of the scope where I called the function (I solved by inputting the numbers they represented rather than setting variables for them).